# Intersecting images of unit Disk by a Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Let $D$ be the unit Disk on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and $T=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$ then what is $\bigcap_{n\geq1}T^{n}D$ ?

My thoughts and some results: So far I've calculated the eigalues  which are $2$ and $4$ associated with eigenvectors $u=(-1,1)$ and $v=(1,1)$, also I know that every pair $(x,y$) that satisfies $10x^{2}-12xy+10y^{2} = 64$ is mapped into the unit circle by $T$ and that those pairs satisfying $136x^{2}-240xy+136y^{2} = 64^{2}$ are mapped by $T^{2}$ into the unit circle. I tried to prove that the intersection is a line but had no success then noted that the Disk is mapped in an ellipse with interior so I guess it can't be a line but rather the whole Disk but I have no idea how to prove the result.

Comment: Hint: show that $T^{n-1}D\subseteq T^nD$. BTW, the intersection is *not* $D$ because you’re computing the intersection for $n\ge1$, not $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you apply the linear transformation, you stretch the circle by a factor of 2 in the direction of $u$ and stretch it by 4 in the direction of $v$.

Imagine how this would look if you stretched the plane in the $x$-direction by 2 and the $y$-direction by 4; we're in the same situation, just after a rotation and a reflection!

Comment: alphacapture, you need just a rotation
$(u,v)\mapsto(e_1,e_2)=\mathcal{E}_2$ already in $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: The hint from alphacapture was - I guess - "try to do the same exercise with the diagonal matrix with $2$ and $4$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @Tancredi I added a reflection because I wanted to preserve the direction of $u$ and $v$;  perhaps I should have made the $x$-axis stretch by 4 and the $y$-axis by 2, but I wanted to keep the order of the axes as the one that you expect by the name.

Comment: My fault, i thought $u$ and $v$ were just two eigenvectors from $2$ and $4$ respectively. I now realized reading all the original post that they were already defined. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, whose columns are eigenvectors you obtained. Then
$$TP=P\Lambda$$
where
$$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$
whose diagonal terms are eigenvalues associated with the eigenvectors. Then 
$$T=P\Lambda P^{-1}$$
It can be verified (by direct calculation) that
$$T^n=P\Lambda^nP^{-1}$$
Suppose $(x,y)=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ is any point on the unit circle, then
$$T^n \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2^n \left( 2^{n-1} (\sin \theta + \cos \theta) -(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)/2 \right) \\ 2^n \left( 2^{n-1}(\sin \theta + \cos \theta )+(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)/2\right) \end{bmatrix}$$
gives the point under transformation. Call it $(x_n,y_n)$.

Now you can proceed to prove that this contains the unit disk. Note that $(x_n,y_n)$ is on a ellipse.